# How can I add activityIndicator during viewload while fetching data from web services?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6.1

How I add an `UIActivityIndicatorView` before the viewload. I am fetching data from a **web server**.

**Here is my code**

```
spinner=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225, 115, 30, 30)];
[spinner setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[spinner setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[self.view addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];


objCountryPreferences=[[CountryPreferences alloc]init];
objLanguagePreference=[[LanguagePreference alloc]init];
objMobilePrefixParser=[[MobilePrefixParser alloc]init];
```

**//this  is calling different web services**

```
[objMobilePrefixParser getMobilePrefix];
[objLanguagePreference  languagePreference];
[objCountryPreferences getCountryIdArr];
```

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: Sorry I can't and this kind of comment is not welcome here. It can be flag or your question can be downvote.

Comment: i want to add activity indicator when view is load. and stop after fetching data from web services . can u suggest me what can i do.

Comment: How you are loading data by NSURLConnection or by simple NSData?

Comment: i am load data from  NSURLConnection.

Comment: after making connection object start activity indicator and stop it in delegate method connectionDidFinishLoading.

Answer (score 1):

Add ActivityIndicator in separate method and call it using

```
[self performSelector:@selector(addActivityIndicator) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the progress indicator is not animating. If YES, you need to perform startAnimating in separate thread.
[spinner performSelector:@selector(startAnimating)]

Answer (score 0):

**Create spinner :**

```
  self.spinner=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    self.spinner.frame=CGRectMake(152,183,60,60);
    // display spinner in StatusBar it Optional for you
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    [self.spinner sizeToFit ];    
      /*-----------Change Size of UIActivityIndicatorView-------------*/
        self.spinner.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
    [self.webView addSubview:self.spinner];
```

**Use Delegate method of UIWebView:**

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [self.spinner startAnimating];
     // display  spinner in StatusBar it Optional for you
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [self.spinner stopAnimating];
    // Remove  spinner in StatusBar it Optional for you
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

}
```